ISPconfig/Nginx/wordpress to nginx proxy manager | wordpress using permalinks/postname
I am migrating my wordpress site from Ispconfig/Apache to Ispconfig/Nginx and introducing Nginx proxy manager in the mix. The problem seems to be the following:

htaccess is not enabled in nginx
are the php directs working ?

I am using ispconfig server with Nginx
A site is enable on ispconfig listening on port 801
The site is installed with wordpress using php-fpm7.4
On that same server i am using Nginx proxy manager in a docker container.
With some adjustment to the wp-config.php i am able to have a functional wordpress site using default permalinks. The config added to wp-config.php is:
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

if( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false )
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
else
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'off';

define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com');

So far so good. My site is functioning with urls like https://example.com/?page_id=503
My goals is my site to be functioning like: https://example.com/offerings
What i have tried (alot but i ll try to list most):

Changing the config in nginx proxy manage config for my site by adding:
Since the proxy manager does not have direct access to the php file socket i mounted the /var/run/php/ to /var/run2 in the container
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }     
 location ~ \.php$ {
 include fastcgi.conf;        
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run2/php7.4-fpm.sock;


convert php-fpm7.4 service to listen on tcp instead of file socket


When i activate this config i only see in the access log:
[01/Jun/2024:23:14:07 +0000] - 404 404 - GET https www.example.com "/blog/" [Client 172.18.0.1]    
[Length 858] [Gzip -] [Sent-to example.com] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;
rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" "https://www.example.com/" 
[01/Jun/2024:23:14:07 +0000] - - 499 - GET https www.example.com "/favicon.ico" [Client  
172.18.0.1] [Length 0] [Gzip -] [Sent-to example.com] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 
x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" "https://www.example.com/blog/"

I have also tried to convert my htaccess file to nginx with online converters and corporate this into my nginx proxy manager config
Default config:
proxy config in NPM:
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# www.example.com
# ------------------------------------------------------------
server {
    set $forward_scheme http;
    set $server         "EXAMPLE.COM";
    set $port           801;
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    #listen [::]:443;
    server_name www.EXAMPLE.COM;
   # Let's Encrypt SSL
   include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;
   include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-24/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-24/privkey.pem;
   access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-15_access.log proxy;
   error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-15_error.log warn;
   location / {
   # Proxy!
   include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
   }
   # Custom
   include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
   }


All questions about Wordpress are out of scope here at Super User.

Turns out i was fishing in the wrong pond. My settings needs to be done on ispconfig side not the NPM side.
